# Julia string format "if"

Tags: python, string, if-statement, format, julia

In Python, `if` may be used in a situation such as the following for optional string formatting.

```
bar = 3
"{n} bar{s}".format(n=bar, s='s' if bar != 1 else '')
# "3 bars"

bar = 1
"{n} bar{s}".format(n=bar, s='s' if bar != 1 else '')
# "1 bar"
```

Julia uses the dollar sign for string formatting.

```
foo = 3
"foo $foo"  # "foo 3"
```

Is it possible to simply mirror the functionality of the Python code using Julia?

Comment: Yes. The `$` interpolation method works with expressions in paranenthesis. In this case `"$bar bar$(bar != 1 ? 's' : "")"` is equivalent to python results.

Comment: @DanGetz This works perfectly. Adding this as an Answer would be greatly appreciated - would love to resolve this question and mark your solution as Correct.

Comment: Pythons inline if is just julia's (and C  and other languages) ternary statement.
Python `a if b else c`  is julia's `b ? a : c`
(and equiv to Lua's `b and a or c`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The `$` interpolation method works with expressions in parenthesis. In this case, `$bar bar$(bar != 1 ? 's' : "")` is equivalent to the Python results.

As @Oxinabox mentioned, Python's inline `if` corresponds to Julia's ternary operator. In Julia the ternary operator `a ? b : c` is a handy shortcut for `if a b ; else c ; end`. Note this means `1==2 ? foo() : bar()` does not evaluate `foo()`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to everything @DanGetz said, you may also want to check out the [Formatting package](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Formatting.jl) – it's explicitly designed to offer more Python-like formatting facilities for Julia.

Comment: Can `printfmt` be used to fomat matrices, like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819425/how-to-specify-the-format-for-printing-an-array-of-floats-in-julia) asks.