# Julia print function printing array of UInt32 as hexadecimal

Tags: julia

When I am printing an array of UInt32 number, Julia's print function is printing it as hexadecimal numbers. It is even displaying in workspace as hexadecimal numbers. Why is it so? And how could I print it in decimal notation?

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819425/how-to-specify-the-format-for-printing-an-array-of-floats-in-julia/38819614

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such decision is discussed [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1210) and [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/3450).

For a decimal rapresentation of a `v` array of `UInt32`:

```
print.(v)
```

Comment: VERY WEIRD syntax in Julia. but this works, provided v is a scalar.
otherwise, if you have a nested list of UInt32/ UInt16, use a nested for loop to unpack the unsigned integers and do print.(scalar)